# Image doesn't load after encoding blob from database(php,mysql,laravel)

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, image, blob

I'm trying to create a picture for every contact.

this is the `store()` method in my controller:

```
public function store()
{

    $attributes = request()->validate([
        'user_id' => ['required'],
        'avatar'  => ['required',],
        'ime'     => ['required', 'min:3'],
        'prezime' => ['required', 'min:3'],
        'broj'    => ['required', 'min:3'],
    ]);
    
    Kontakt::create($attributes);

    return redirect('/imenikk');
}
```

this is the `create.blade.php`:

```
<form method="POST" action="/imenikk">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="container text-center">
    <label for="ime">Ime</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" name="ime"
            placeholder="Ime">
    <label for="prezime">Prezime</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" name="prezime"
            placeholder="Prezime">
    <label for="broj">Broj</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" name="broj"
            placeholder="Broj">
            <br>
            <input type="file" name="avatar" accept="image/*">
            <br>
        <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value='{{$user_id}}'>      
                
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Dodaj
    </div>
</form>
```

And this is on `show.blade.php`:

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,{{ chunk_split(base64_encode($imenikk->avatar)) }}" height="500" width="500">
<img src ="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{base64_encode($imenikk->avatar)}}" height="200" width="200">
```

Neither of these 2 are working.. I get this but the image doesn't load:

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,SU1HXzYxODQuSlBH" height="500" width="500">
```

This is how my db looks when I create a contact with picture:

[image]

Also I have managed to decode this
img src="data:image/jpg;base64,SU1HXzYxODQuSlBH

and I get the image name when I decode it yet the page still doesn't display the image.

Comment: base64 code string cannot be that short. try to test your base64 string [here](https://tsaikoga.github.io/it-tools/web/index.html#/image64-page)

Comment: It is different and much longer over there, what am I doing wrong? I am encoding the file name, am I supposed to encode something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your base64 code is wrong.

Try to get the real base64 code from image file, and store in database.

```php
public function store()
{

    $attributes = request()->validate([
        'user_id' => ['required'],
        'avatar'  => ['required',],
        'ime'     => ['required', 'min:3'],
        'prezime' => ['required', 'min:3'],
        'broj'    => ['required', 'min:3'],
    ]);
    $file = request()->file('avatar');
    $imagedata = file_get_contents($file->getRealPath());;
    $base64 = base64_encode($imagedata);
    $attributes['avatar'] = $base64;
    Kontakt::create($attributes);

    return redirect('/imenikk');
}
```

then store it in your field,
and display it like this:

```php
<img src={{ "data:image/jpg;base64,".$imenikk->avatar }} height="500" width="500">
```

Comment: What do I put in 
$file = $request->file('your_file');
I thought I am supposed to put data from blob in database? 
Or do I have to manually add images to certain folder instead of uploading them to mysql through form input?

Comment: @PavleTosic you are uploading an avatar file to store in database. so you need to call `request()->file('avatar')` to get the file.

Comment: This is my show() method
    public function show(Request $request,Kontakt $imenikk)
    {   
        //$kontakt = Kontakt::get();
        $file = $request->file('avatar');
        $imagedata = file_get_contents($file->getRealPath());;
        $base64 = base64_encode($imagedata);

        $imenikk->avatar = $base64;
        return view('show', compact('imenikk'));
    }

And I get this error when I try to open the contact page

Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
Call to a member function getRealPath() on null

Comment: @PavleTosic I mean in your `store()` action, you need to use `file_get_contents` and `base64_encode`, then store it in avatar field.

Comment: I have this in store() 
        $attributes = request()->validate([
            'user_id' => ['required'],
            'avatar' => ['required',],  
            'ime' => ['required', 'min:3'],
            
            'prezime' => ['required', 'min:3'],
            'broj' => ['required', 'min:3']
        ]);
        
    
        
        
        Kontakt::create($attributes);

        return redirect('/imenikk');


How do I set predefined value in validate and add it to $attributes variable so that I can use the create() with all arguments I need to pass into my database?

Comment: Can you write me a complete store() method including the code from method I wrote in question? I can't seem to manage to make it work, i still get (Call to a member function getRealPath() on null) error for some reason

Comment: I still get (Call to a member function getRealPath() on null) when I use the method you wrote

Comment: When i do this
$file = request()->file('avatar');
        dd($file);
I get null!

Comment: @PavleTosic did u really upload the avatar? see [laravel-file](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests#files)

Comment: I have edited your answer with my solution, I got it to work, thanks for your help!